# Foreman/Katello error with product synchronization

Tags: centos7, foreman, katello

We have Foreman 1.12.4 w Katello 3.1 installed on Centos 7.2

After a small error with pip in which yum-controlled software was updated and broke our Katello install, I rolled back as best I could and set off a fresh sync on all products.

Some products worked fine, but about half return this error

```
RPM1004: Error retrieving metadata: Not found
```

I can't see anything online that would suggest a solution to this error. There have been some suggested solutions - for eg "install the errata", which would be possible except the Katello product is one that won't syncronise.

Does anyone know how I might go about syncing against the repos? Here is one of the repos that isn't syncing - it looks like there is metadata in there (by which I mean, there is a repodata dir with files in it).

https://fedorapeople.org/groups/katello/releases/yum/3.1/pulp/el7/x86_64/

To be honest I'm a bit lost - I understand the error message (can't find the metadata) but I can't find a solution - it is as simple as finding the metadata and putting it in the right place on the filesystem somewhere, or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL on the repo and make sure its not using a subversion in there. I also had this problem but found that I had a subversion in the URL. Once I changed it to just use the major version, all is back to normal now.

Bad: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/

Good: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/

Hope that helps.